# UNIX : TEXT PROCESSING ISSUE USING CUT

Tags: shell, unix, awk, cut

I have a CSV File '1.txt' with fields as

```
#1.txt
Name,Activity,Address,URL,Number,Company
```

and I wanted to be in the format

```
#2.txt
Name,URL,Address,Activity,Number,Company
```

I tried using cut

```
cut -d, -f1,4,3,2,5,6 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The output ( `2.txt` ) remains the same as Input.

Can some one help me on this ? As file size is too large(500000 Lines)  to process in sheets/excel.

Comment: Try cutting one field at a time to see if you're even matching the delimiter correctly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I checked each and every field one at a time ! No issues with that ! It's correct !

Comment: Then....what's the problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Oh  ! great got it ! Jon ! keep incrementing the selective fields one at a time ! It works ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `cut` manpage, selected input is written in the same order that it is read. So you have to use awk instead:

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$4,$3,$2,$5,$6}' < 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

No point hard-coding every field number, just swap the 2 fields you care about:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {t=$2;$2=$4;$4=t} 1' file
Name,URL,Address,Activity,Number,Company
```